# Best way to persist static text

Tags: android, text-formatting

My app uses a lot of static text and I'm trying to find an optimal way to persist and display that text. For now, I don't need to focus on localizing the text so, all the text goes into the `strings.xml` and that presents a lot of formatting nightmares.

Of course, it is not 100% static content, I sometimes have dynamic values in there which in my case can stay within `strings.xml` so, what is the right way for persisting this static text?

Comment: if i were you i would place theme in the static string array.

Comment: You said there's already strings that are staying in the `strings.xml`, so I would keep the text there.  Otherwise, you're going to have a bunch of text just scattered in multiple locations. That's going to be confusing for anybody reading that code.  Plus, it'll be easier to update when you *do* care about localization.

Comment: True but I want to ensure formatting is consistent across the app. Yes, I'm not looking to split the strings into different files across the app.

Comment: can you define what you mean by "it is not 100% static content"?

Comment: I add format arguments for replacing a string or decimal characters as mentioned here: [String Formatting](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)

Answer (score 3):

Static text content is exactly what you want to use `strings.xml` for, and you automatically get the added bonus of easier localization as you can have different `strings.xml` for the different languages.  No code changes required, just different XML files.

Dynamic content is going to be content which changes based on user input.  You can still use `strings.xml` to store the static portion (if any) of that dynamic content.  Like the "format" string you may pass to `String.format()` or something similar.

Use the resources support for this, it is exactly what it was intended to do (and do it efficiently.)

Comment: Yes but apart from basic formatting to support multiple lines, I'm asking if there is a better approach or are my options limited to ```strings.xml```?

Comment: Your best, most flexible and maintainable approach is to use `strings.xml`.  The other option(s) would include having the strings fixed in your code, which is not good for maintenance or internationalization.

Answer (score 3):

Your comment is contradictory; you say:

> For now, I don't need to focus on localizing the text so, all the text goes into the strings.xml

if you don't need Localizing, then *why are you using `strings.xml`*?

Of course, the answer is because regardless of localizing, `strings.xml` is the perfect place for this.

I don't know what kind of nightmares you have with it, but it's not different from any other string:

E.g. of a strings.xml:

```
<string name="refresh">Refresh</string>
<string name="order_placed" formatted="false">Order Placed: %s</string>
```

You can later use the same formatter for them:

`getString(R.string.order_placed, "3pm")`

will output:

`Order Placed: 3pm`

If you need new lines…

```
<string name="error">Something bad happened.\nPlease try again.</string>
```

will output:

```
Something bad happened.
Please try again.
```

And so forth.

Additionally, if you have trouble *naming* your resources, I've been following more or less [this idea](http://jeroenmols.com/blog/2016/03/07/resourcenaming/) and despite the shortcomings described at the bottom, they haven't been a big deal with Android Studio fancy refactoring tools.

Comment: Understood and it appears that there is no better option apart from formatting the ```strings.xml```.

Comment: I'm interested in hearing your "Nightmares" about strings.

Comment: Mostly formatting (new lines, among others) for various form factors.

Comment: And auto-spacing for different form factors. Right now, we show ellipses after a couple of lines but I personally feel ellipses are not intuitive. May be I should show expand/collapse icon and also make the expanded text show in-place.

Comment: Well I agree with those things, but those are formatting problems, not string problems from a problem's point of view. Those things must be controlled by Span and Text Formatters :)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class called StaticBuffer or something with a static String array as a data member.

```
class StaticBuffer
  { 
    static String array[]; 
  }
```

Then you could initialize it in your onCreate() or any other function and use it.As it is static it's values will reflect the changes that you make everywhere.

Eg :

```
//Initialization

StaticBuffer.array=new String[10];

//Usage

StaticBuffer.array[0]="Item1";
```

PS: I got this idea from a friend of mine. :)

Comment: Honestly, it's a really bad idea :)

Comment: In case you're wondering why, I can name 3 things that came to my head: Theading, Nullcheck/BoundsCheck, Lookups. Those things would be an unneeded problem by using this.